# How to call a method in a activity if a fragment is loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hey there I have a scenario . There is an activity which contains 2 fragments. Now i want to call a method in MainActivity.class that if fragment 1 is loaded run following method else if fragment 2 is loaded run this method

```
if (fragment1.loaded())
{
call this function
}
if (fragment2.loaded())
{
call this function
}
```

Comment: @UmarGhaffar, `if(fragment1!=null && fragment1.isVisible())` will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find Fragment in Activity

Comment: use `var fragment=supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container)` in kotlin

Comment: then check     if (fragment is FirstFragment){ (activity as ActivityName).method()}

Comment: same process follow on second fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can call that method within the fragments themselves to ensure they are loaded.

In the **onCreate()** method of both fragments you can call

```
(activity as YourActivity).activityMethod()
```

Remember that fragments can have access to their parent activity and, therefore, to accessible methods.

If you want to chain those methods you should implement listeners for both fragments and make parent activity to extend them.

Answer (score 0):

if you want return call back when the Fragment Loaded method was triggered. You must create an interface for the get the call back in Activity.

you must create new Fragment in your activity and You have to override this interface here. When code is working Your interface triggered in your fragment and this method call back returned in your activity.

you can use onClickListener interface as a reference for your require. it is using for the same action.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global interface to watch any fragment's life cyrcle，It's easy to be coded.